# Creating a new excel sheet along with writing and appending data from a php/html form

Tags: php, database, phpexcel, forms

Here is my(newbie to programming) question -

I want to know the process and code to create a randomly named excel file and filling it up through an html form or php form.

The exact situation is this -

The user enters the site - 
Fill some data with the help of a php form. Then a new excel file should be created and no matter how many times the user fills up that form within that session, all of that data should be saved in that particular excel sheet.

New session, new user, new file.

Please someone help me out, i am in real need of this phenomenon for some cause. I know there are many programmers with excellent knowledge and programming skills who are at this website.

Thanking you from heart in advance.

Comment: So what is your actual problem? Creating the form (note: there are only html forms on web pages, there is no such thing as a php form)? Submitting the form? Accessing form data from a PHP script? Generating a random filename? Writing data to an excel file?

Comment: I am sorry sir, seems like that was my fault. I could not make it clear. I know how to create the html form. What i don't know is how to create the excel sheet, write the data into it and append it with next response from the same form with may be, may not be same data. Thanx for ur attention.

Comment: Start by breaking down the problem into small steps.... step #1 - you need to create a form; step #2 - you need to submit that form to a php script; step #3 - that PHP script has to read the data that has been submitted in the form; etc...

Comment: The form has been created already. But i don't know to submit that data which is stored in PHP variables to an excel sheet.

Comment: Start by looking at any of the myriad of libraries for PHP like [PHPExcel](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) that can write Excel format files

Comment: Okay! I think i have to check out PHPExcel first. If i'll be having problems, will get back to you through here.